# Cheap way to make cardboard box waterproof?

Tags: waterproofing

I will be *attempting* to make some concrete planters with two cardboard boxes. Below is the DIY that I will follow:

As you can see, the interior of the outer box & the exterior of the inner box must be waterproof.

So the instructions say to use duct tape for this, but duct tape is expensive. I'm thinking there may be a cheaper way, like maybe spraying the box with something to make the cardboard waterproof.

Does this make sense or is duct tape the only way?

[image]

Comment: I can’t think of a cheaper way that doesn’t compromise the cardboard. You can generally get free cardboard out of the dumpster behind any grocery.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean In my area, most of the grocery stores that used to leave the empty boxes out back now recycle them - you now have to ask inside when they're stocking the shelves, though usually they are quite happy to see the boxes actually get reused.

Answer (score 2):

How about **plastic bags**?   You will need 2.  Put inner box inside one.  Leave bag open at top so concrete can push air out of the bag and flatten it against inner box.

Put bagged box inside another bag.  Then double bagged box inside outer box.

Pour concrete between the 2 bags.  Bags will flatten against boxes as they fill and contain concrete between the 2 boxes.  Peel off bags after concrete sets.  You may get some aesthetically pleasing wrinkles in the final product.

Added bonus: it will be easy to retrieve boxes from final product.

@manassehkatz is right about the concrete collapsing the boxes.  You could address this with a hole (or a pile of sand).  Dig a hole in the ground large enough to contain planter.  Fill inner box with dirt to fortify it against collapse.  Put box/bag mold into the hole and put dirt down around outer box.  That will keep it from bursting outwards from weight of wet concrete.  Or you could just fill inside box with sand and wrap outer box with ropes.

Answer (score 1):

Start with waxed cardboard, commonly found in boxes for produce that might be wet.

You could wax your own, but you won't do as good a job and it won't be nearly as inexpensive, and will take more time (so costs more in money and time, at which point you might just as well spend the money on a cardboard tube form made for the purpose.)

A more sustainable approach (perhaps depending on how many planters you, or you and your friends, want) is to go with properly shaped wooden forms, and oil them before pouring (oil would probably degrade the cardboard too much) which can be used to make as many planters as you want from one set of forms. They do need to be built and shaped so that they can be removed for reuse, but it's not terribly difficult.

Comment: Thanks. What's a cardboard tube form?

Comment: @rbhat A tube [like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SAKRETE-8-in-x-48-in-Concrete-Form-Tube-65470075/100321209).  They are made to be used as forms for pouring concrete posts/footings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with duct tape isn't just the cost, it is the hassle. Plus, cardboard isn't exactly the strongest material - you run a real risk of the outer cardboard collapsing under the weight of the concrete.

If I were doing this, I would probably try plywood. The question, of course, is how inexpensively can you get plywood of the right size. You may be able to find scrap plywood at a construction site, but if not then head over to your local big box home improvement store. Currently (subject to change daily!), you can get an 11/32", 4' x 8' sheet of plywood at Home Depot in my area (Maryland, USA) for $14.03. Borrow a saw (a good table saw would be easiest to get precision cuts but there are other ways) and cut inner and outer forms from the plywood. A box of screws to put it together and you can make a whole bunch of planters (as long as they are the same size) with the same forms.